# How to mange user from class in asp.net core(identity 3.0.0 Rc1)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

I just started asp.net core  and now I want to manage users in a class
in mvc 5 it's so easy like this code:

```
  var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

But I don,t know how I can mange users in **identity 3.0.0 Rc1**.
I hope you can suggest a good way to me

Comment: What do you want achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

@regnauld ask good question ;) However answering for general case...

Most of 'user management' actions you can find in `UserManager` class.

Other way:

First, read [Introduction to Identity v3](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/identity.html), please.

Then create new MVC Core project in Visual Studio with selected `Authentication: Individual User Accounts` option...

[image]

... this give you default MVC project with 'ready to use' `AccountController` and `ManageController`, **and there you can find good examples** how You can mange users in Identity 3.

Comment: I think the question is about using the Usermanager In a more generic way. in MVC core the usermanager is injected into the controller by default. How would you access them from outside a controller?